# Disabling ordering in jQuery DataTables stills loads with order icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have a 4 columns DataTable that needs ordering, except for first column. I tried using `"columns": [ {"orderable": false}, null, null, null ]`, but the first column shows the ordering icon (caret) on page load.

When I order another column, the icon disappear from first column, but there is still the space where it was, breaking the column width. Is there any way to REALLY disable the ordering, in a way that it also doesn't add any special padding?

**SOLVED:**

@ShaktiPhartiyal answer fixed the sorting problems. The width problem was fixed by setting the `autowidth` option to `false` and using a little CSS.

> CSS part

```
table.dataTable thead tr th:first-child,
table.dataTable tbody tr td:first-child {
    width: 0px;
}
```

> DataTables options

```
$(table).DataTable({
    "paging":   false,
    "columnDefs" : [
        { targets: 0, sortable: false},
    ],
    "order": [[ 3, "asc" ]],
    "autoWidth": false
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you disable sorting for a column, the dataTables sort order still remain. By default order is `[0, 'asc']`; simply set order to target the #2 column instead :

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    //....
    order: [[ 1, "asc" ]] //column indexes is zero based
});
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6k26o7mk/)

Comment: This solves the problem with the sorting! But I'm still having the problem with DataTables expanding the `<th>` element for the first column, like there is a caret. Exploring the final code after the DataTable, it defines the width of the `<th>`, while in your example it doesn't.

Comment: Put your code in a jsfiddle and share the link here

Comment: Couldn't replicate the code because of iCheck lib. I found that ignoring the .css file from DataTables fix the `<th>` width problem, but mess with the caret for the other columns.

Comment: Managed to fix it by using the `"autowidth": false` option! I'll accept your answer and edit my question to add the information. Thanks!

Comment: OK, means the issue is somewhat also related to the width of a column is growing/shrinking on ordering. Enjoy the coding !!

Answer (score 0):

To disable ordering / sorting in datatables you can use the following parameter:

```
"aoColumns": [{ "bSortable": false }, null],
```

The code tells datatable to disable sorting in the first column.

Comment: This option disabled all sorting. In the case there was any change between versions, I'm currently using DataTables 1.10.13.

Comment: @Minoru that is fine. Remember that you need to pass the number of elements equal to the number of columns you have, simply pass null in the array index where you want the columns to be sortable